# In GitHub is there a way to notify the author of a PR that someone started a review?

Tags: git, github

A lot of times I push updates when someone is in the middle of a review. Is there a way to notify the author of a PR that someone *started* a review?

Is there any Git software such as UpSource that does anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

Push to your fork or a feature branch, create a pull request once the whole change is done. Reviews only happen on pull requests.

When fixing problems detected during the review, create `--fixup` commits. Do a `--rebase --autosquash` and force push just before merging once the reviewers are happy.

That way, you can't push *in the middle of a review*.